# Animation between fragments

Tags: android, animation, fragment

I want animation between fragments. 
The second fragment should slide out from bottom right and the first(current fragment should stay as it is) this should happen on click of a FAB Button.

What I have tried.

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom_right,R.anim.stay);

                ft.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment, "XYZ");
                ft.addToBackStack("XYZ");
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                ft.commit();
```

`slide_in_from_bottom_right.xml`:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="600"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        />
</set>
```

`stay.xml`:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:duration="600"/>
</set>
```

The problem is that I am not able to see the actual sliding in.
What have I missed here?

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the first fragment as it is then you don't need to define animation resource for the first fragment.

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom_right,0);
```

I just updated your `slide_in_from_bottom_right.xml` to translate the view perfectly from `100% x and y to 0% x and y`.

> slide_in_from_bottom_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate 
  android:fromYDelta="100%p" 
  android:fromXDelta="100%p" 
  android:toYDelta="0%p"
  android:toXDelta="0%p"
  android:duration="600"
  android:fillAfter="true"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
/>
```

You can also set the pop animation for the second fragment when you back from the second fragment to the first fragment.

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom_right,0,0,R.anim.pop_slide_in_from_top_left.xml);
```

> pop_slide_in_from_top_left.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="600">

<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```