# fragment to fragment transition with FloatingActionButton Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

There are two fragments ChatFragment and CreateGroupFragment. When FloatingActionButton is selected in ChatFragment, CreateGroupFragment should come screen. But when click this button app closing.

this is my code

```
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        FloatingActionButton fab=(FloatingActionButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.addgroup);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content,new CreateGroupFragment(),
                        "Fragmentcreate").addToBackStack("Fragmentcreate").commit();

            }
        });

    }
```

[this is chatFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THBDm.png)

[image]

crash

> --------- beginning of crash 11-29 16:36:43.823 2656-2656/com.example.asus.buddy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main Process: com.example.asus.buddy, PID: 2656
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be
>   cast to android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton at
>   com.example.asus.buddy.CreateGroupFragment.onActivityCreated(CreateGroupFragment.java:159)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2363)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1442)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: Please follow SO guidelines to form a question [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [keypoints to enhance qulity of question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0):

here you can use simple transitions while starting your fragment.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out).add(R.id.content,new CreateGroupFragment(),
                        "Fragmentcreate").addToBackStack("Fragmentcreate").commit();

            }
        });
```

read more about adding fragment transition [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments)

Medium [link](https://medium.com/bynder-tech/how-to-use-material-transitions-in-fragment-transactions-5a62b9d0b26b)

[Using](https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb) shared elements

Comment: It didnt change. has same error which is app stopped.

Comment: RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Comment: problem is with Fab button you are getting problem because you are casting Relative layout into Floating button please corrent below line  and check again
FloatingActionButton fab=(FloatingActionButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.addgroup);

Comment: i advice you to intialize Flaoting action button in onCreateView() and set onClick listener there only

Comment: I try it in onCreateView , it give error FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.addgroup);

Comment: dont use getActivity, use view object instead which you will be returning in onCreateView()

Comment: FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.addgro‌​up)

Comment: can you just add your code here in question on which fragment its happening

Answer (score 0):

The ID you are referencing is wrong and that of a RelativeLayout, therefore the casting issue. Have a look at the exact FAB id, currently `R.id.addgroup` is of your layout and not your FAB.