# Android how to move a fragment with an animation on screen

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, fragment

I am making an app which is working with a google map, i have a place search fragment which should be invisible and only appear when i press a button to add new places as markers on the map through some kind of simple animation, just moving vertically to the center from the bottom for example. How do i make the fragment appear on the middle of the screen with an animation since it is a fragment and not just a view?

here is the layout file :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapsActivityRaw">


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawermenu">


</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tb_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layout_constraint1">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            map:cameraZoom="10"
            tools:context="com.example.styledmap.MapsActivityRaw" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_delete_marker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/map"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="@string/tv_delete"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_add_place"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/map"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.872" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the activity containing the map:

```
public class MapsActivityRaw extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markers = new ArrayList<>();
    private Geocoder gcd;
    private static final String TAG = MapsActivityRaw.class.getSimpleName();
    private LatLng mLatLong;
    private String city;
    private Location location;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private TextView tv_delete;
    private LinkedHashMap<Integer, MarkerOptions> markerHashMap;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private Toolbar mActionBar;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private ConstraintSet mConstraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    private ConstraintSet mConstraintSet2 = new ConstraintSet();
    private ConstraintLayout mConstraintLayout;
    private boolean mOld = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Fragment fragment_place_search = new Fragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.place_autocomplete, fragment_place_search).commit();

        // Retrieve the content view that renders the map.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_raw);


        Button btnAddPlace = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add_place);
        btnAddPlace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mOld){
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(fragment_place_search).commit();
                    mOld = !mOld;
                } else {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(fragment_place_search).commit();
                    mOld = !mOld;
                }
            }
        });


        mActionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mActionBar);


        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MapsActivityRaw.this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.closed_drawer);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //Set up views
        tv_delete = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_delete_marker);

        //Set up Database
        PlacesDBHelper placesDBHelper = new PlacesDBHelper(this);
        mDb = placesDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        // Get the SupportMapFragment and register for the callback
        // when the map is ready for use.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        markerHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        //Set up location manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider;

        try {
            provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            mLatLong = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Retrieve markers from db
        mCursor = getAllPlaces();
        retrieveMarkers(mCursor);


        //Set up search bar for places
        PlaceAutocompleteFragment placeAutoComplete = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete);
        placeAutoComplete.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.placeautocomplete_hint));
        AutocompleteFilter filter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder().setTypeFilter(5).build();
        placeAutoComplete.setFilter(filter);
        placeAutoComplete.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                //Retrieve information about selected place and zoom into it
                mLatLong = place.getLatLng();
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(mLatLong.latitude, mLatLong.longitude))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                        .zoom(4)                   // Sets the zoom
                        .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                Log.d("Maps", "Place selected: " + place.getName());


                //Retrieve location information from latitude and longitude
                gcd = new Geocoder(MapsActivityRaw.this, Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    List<Address> address = gcd.getFromLocation(mLatLong.latitude, mLatLong.longitude, 1);
                    city = address.get(0).getLocality();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                //Check if selected place was already added

                mCursor = getAllPlaces();
                retrieveMarkers(mCursor);
                for (int i = 0; i < markerHashMap.size(); i++) {
                    MarkerOptions marker = (new ArrayList<>(markerHashMap.values()).get(i));
                    if (marker.getPosition().latitude == mLatLong.latitude && marker.getPosition().longitude == mLatLong.longitude) {
                        Snackbar duplicate = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), R.string.snackbar_duplicate, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        View sb_duplicateView = duplicate.getView();
                        TextView tv_sb_duplicate = (TextView) sb_duplicateView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                        tv_sb_duplicate.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                        sb_duplicateView.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                        duplicate.show();
                        return;
                    }

                }


                Snackbar placeAdded = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), R.string.snackbar_place_added, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                View sb_placeAddedView = placeAdded.getView();
                sb_placeAddedView.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                TextView tv_sb_placeAdded = (TextView) sb_placeAddedView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                tv_sb_placeAdded.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                placeAdded.show();

                MarkerOptions currentMarker = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(mLatLong)
                        .title(city)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                mMap.addMarker(currentMarker);

                //Add place into database
                addNewPlace(city, mLatLong.latitude, mLatLong.longitude);


            }


            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                Log.d("Maps", "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });

    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map when it's available.
     * The API invokes this callback when the map is ready for use.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        //Initialize the map
        mMap = googleMap;

        //Setting default map rules
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);

        //Disable Map Toolbar:
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                return true;
            }
        });


        //Configure custom infowindow through InfoWindowAdapter
        CustomInfoWindowAdapter adapter = new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(MapsActivityRaw.this);
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(adapter);


        //Set onclicklistener for InfoWindow
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivityRaw.this, MarkerActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        //Set onclicklistener for Marker dragging to delete it
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
                tv_delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tv_delete.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
                LatLng position = marker.getPosition();
                Projection projection = mMap.getProjection();
                Point screenPosition = projection.toScreenLocation(position);
                int tv_delete_top_boundry = tv_delete.getTop();
                if (screenPosition.y >= tv_delete_top_boundry) {
                    tv_delete.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                } else {
                    tv_delete.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                String string_id = marker.getSnippet();
                int id = Integer.parseInt(string_id);
                LatLng position = marker.getPosition();
                Projection projection = mMap.getProjection();
                Point screenPosition = projection.toScreenLocation(position);
                int tv_delete_top_boundry = tv_delete.getTop();

                if (screenPosition.y >= tv_delete_top_boundry) {
                    boolean test = removeMarker(id);
                    marker.remove();
                }
                mMap.clear();
                mCursor = getAllPlaces();
                retrieveMarkers(mCursor);
                setMarkers();
                tv_delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });


        //Set markers retrieved from database on now available map
        setMarkers();

        // Set the button for retrieving the current location and moving camera to it
        try {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //Style the map
        try {
            // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
            // in a raw resource file.
            boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.map_style));

            if (!success) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
            }
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
        }


        // Position the map's camera
        if (location != null) {
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(mLatLong)      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                    .zoom(3)                   // Sets the zoom
                    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
    }


    // Database function for retrieving current database data in a cursor
    private Cursor getAllPlaces() {
        return mDb.query(
                PlacesContract.PlacesEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                PlacesContract.PlacesEntry._ID
        );
    }


    //Function to add new places into the database
    private long addNewPlace(String name, double latitude, double longitude) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(PlacesContract.PlacesEntry.COLUMN_CITY, name);
        cv.put(PlacesContract.PlacesEntry.COLUMN_LATITUDE, latitude);
        cv.put(PlacesContract.PlacesEntry.COLUMN_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        return mDb.insert(PlacesContract.PlacesEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }

    //Remove marker from db
    private boolean removeMarker(int id) {
        return mDb.delete(PlacesContract.PlacesEntry.TABLE_NAME, PlacesContract.PlacesEntry._ID + "=" + id, null) > 0;
    }


    //Function to set all markers retrieved from database
    private void setMarkers() {
        ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markerOptionsList = new ArrayList<>(markerHashMap.values());

        for (int i = 0; i < markerOptionsList.size(); i++) {
            MarkerOptions option = markerOptionsList.get(i);
            mMap.addMarker(option);
        }
    }


    //Retrieve all markers from database
    private void retrieveMarkers(Cursor cursor) {
        markers.clear();
        markerHashMap.clear();
        cursor = getAllPlaces();
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            if (!cursor.moveToPosition(i)) {
                Log.d("Cursor", "Cursor is empty");
            } else {
                String cCity = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PlacesContract.PlacesEntry.COLUMN_CITY));
                double cLatitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(PlacesContract.PlacesEntry.COLUMN_LATITUDE));
                double cLongitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(PlacesContract.PlacesEntry.COLUMN_LONGITUDE));
                int cId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(PlacesContract.PlacesEntry._ID));
                LatLng cLatLng = new LatLng(cLatitude, cLongitude);
                MarkerOptions cMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions().title(cCity).snippet("" + cId).position(cLatLng).draggable(true).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                markerHashMap.put(cId, cMarkerOptions);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Comment: I suggest looking at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments Specifically `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations` as well as `FragmentTransaction.setTransition.`

Comment: this is useful for replacing fragments, the fragment i want to move to the center of the screen should not replace the map but be animated to appear in front of it until the user enters something while the map is still in the background