# Creating a objectAnimation using percentages

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I created a custom amimation using the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <objectAnimator
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:duration="500"
      android:propertyName="x"
      android:valueFrom="0"
      android:valueTo="-1000"
      android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

Now it works almost like I want, because I am missing a part of my screen. So my question is: How can I make this animation using percentages instead of values?

**EDIT:**
Here is the code about my fragmentanimation:

```
var trans = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
float screenWidth = metrics.WidthPixels;//calculate screen width
double wantValue = 0.5;//set a percentages

ObjectAnimator SlideLeft = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(trans, "translationX", 0, (float)(screenWidth * wantValue));
SlideLeft.SetDuration(500);
SlideLeft.Start();

ObjectAnimator SlideRight = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(trans, "translationX", 0, (float)(screenWidth * -wantValue));
SlideLeft.SetDuration(500);
SlideLeft.Start();

trans.SetCustomAnimations(SlideRight, SlideLeft);
```

With the error:

> cannot convert from 'Android.Animation.ObjectAnimator' to 'int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible in XML to do.However you can set percentages in cs code.

```
TextView textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text_content);
// Here using a textView to have a test    

DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
float screenWidth = metrics.WidthPixels;//calculate screen width
double wantValue = 0.5;//set a percentages
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(textView, "translationX", 0, (float)(screenWidth*wantValue));
objectAnimator.SetDuration(3000);
objectAnimator.Start();
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> And how can I use this for fragments then, because I tried your code with trans.SetCustomAnimations(SlideRight, SlideLeft);

If you want to use **SetCustomAnimations** to set animations , you shoud can set percentages in **XML**.However not using *objectAnimator*, is **translate**.

**slide_left_in.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <translate
      android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
      android:toXDelta="0%p"
      android:duration="500"/>

  <alpha
      android:fromAlpha="0.5"
      android:toAlpha="1.0"
      android:duration="500"/>

</set>
```

**slide_left_out.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <translate
      android:fromXDelta="0%p"
      android:toXDelta="-100%p"
      android:duration="500"/>

  <alpha
      android:fromAlpha="1.0"
      android:toAlpha="0.5"
      android:duration="500"/>

</set>
```

**slide_right_in.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <translate
      android:fromXDelta="100%p"
      android:toXDelta="0%p"
      android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full"/>

  <alpha
      android:fromAlpha="0.5"
      android:toAlpha="1.0"
      android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full"/>

</set>
```

**slide_right_out.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <translate
      android:fromXDelta="0%p"
      android:toXDelta="100%p"
      android:duration="500"/>

  <alpha
      android:fromAlpha="1.0"
      android:toAlpha="0.5"
      android:duration="500"/>

</set>
```

Finally , set in code:

```
var details = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.details) as DetailsFragment;
var trans = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
trans.Replace(Resource.Id.details, details);
trans.SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.slide_right_in,Resource.Animation.slide_left_out,Resource.Animation.slide_left_in,Resource.Animation.slide_right_out);
trans.Commit();
```

If happen this error :

> Unknown animator name: translate occurred

you need to change to V4 Version of Fragment:

```
using Fragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;
```

Comment: And what is `textView`?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk `textView` is a TextView in my project, you can replace it with your view.I have updated answer.

Comment: And how can I use this for fragments then, because I tried your code with `trans.SetCustomAnimations(SlideRight, SlideLeft);` But then it says that it can't convert Animation to int. What am I doing wrong? I created 2 ObjectAnimators btw.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Okey, you can show more code about `SetCustomAnimations` in question.I will check it.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Thanks for updating question.I have updated answer.

Comment: I get this error: `Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{appname.appname/md5daf804607252bb921d2f5ad4f62be09e.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animator name: translate occurred`

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Update code in question.And here is a similar discussion for refer.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments?lq=1

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk You should set four paramaters in `SetCustomAnimations` , this is not similar with `objectAnimator`.

Comment: I did exactly what he did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33992609/10673107. But still error with `translate`?!

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk I have reproduced this error, you should use `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` to **SetCustomAnimations**.Then this error will disappear.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Have you solved it, you can share sample project.I will check it.

Comment: I actually did. I forgot to set the Activity to FragmentActivity, because only then I can use translate!

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Yeah , this need to change to `FragmentActivity`.  *.^

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Glad be helpful .Remember to vote up ,thanks in advance :)