# Fragment transition having a blinking effect

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to put slide animation on a FragmentContainerView. However, the fragment that should appear flickers before starting the animation.

To summarize, when the transaction begins, the current fragment slides out, the next fragment flickers and then slides in.

I'm not asking for direct solutions, but if somebody knows what can cause this kind of bug, because I don't even know what to look at to solve this problem.

Edit: Code samples

FragmentContainerView (XML)

```
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/frame_cigarette"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_activity_filter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
```

Code for fragment transition

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(
                            R.anim.slide_in_right,
                            R.anim.slide_out_left,
                            R.anim.slide_in_left,
                            R.anim.slide_out_right
                        )
                        .replace(
                            R.id.frame_cigarette,
                            CigaretteCravingFragment.newInstance(),
                            CigaretteCravingFragment::class.java.simpleName
                        )
                        .addToBackStack(CigaretteCravingFragment::class.java.simpleName)
                        .commit()
```

Code for an exit slide animation (slide out right)

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

Code for an enter slide animation (slide in left)

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

Comment: Can you include the code and the animations files, please?

Comment: I did put XML and the code for the transaction. Do you need more?

Comment: Could you please include the animations files?

Comment: Added slide in and out animation XML, adding the 2 other ones would be duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved this few moments ago. In my case Im using navigation graph to define all animation between fragments but in your case should work the same because `setCustomAnimations` also can take `@AnimatorRes`. You have to use `ObjectAnimator` and custom layout. Inspiration from: [Animate the transition between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments)

`CustomConstraintLayout.java`

```
public class CustomConstraintLayout extends ConstraintLayout {
    
    public float getXFraction() {
        return getX() / getWidth();
    }

    public float getYFraction() {
        return getY() / getHeight();
    }

    public void setXFraction(float xFraction) {
        final int width = getWidth();
        setX((width > 0) ? (xFraction * width) : -9999);
    }

    public void setYFraction(float yFraction) {
        final int height = getHeight();
        setY((height > 0) ? (yFraction * height) : -9999);
    }
}
```

`slide_in_from_bottom_animator.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="yFraction"
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="@integer/change_view_anim_time"/>
</set>
```

`YourFragment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.yourapp.ui.CustomConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- some stuff -->

</com.yourapp.ui.CustomConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I'm gonna try it, I will answer again to ask you more info or to confirm your solution!