# ObjectAnimator in API Level < 11

Tags: android, android-compatibility

So I'm getting really frustrated with android and the fact half the stuff doesn't work when you roll back the API Level past 11. Why isn't it easy and well done like iOS?!

**The Problem**
I am using `ObjectAnimators` to animate the transitioning between `Fragments`. They work fine in anything with API Level 11 and above. As soon as I change the build target to less than 11 I get problems with it saying it can't found the resource identifiers for attributes such as `propertyName` and `valueType` in the xml file.

**The Question** 
What should I use instead to animate my `Fragment` transitions that will work on API Levels > 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Property Animation`
    Introduced in Android 3.0 (API level 11).

Comment: Sorry for the noob query. I understand we cannot build pre-3.0, but does this also mean that the animations using Property animation (on an app built using 4.4) will not run on devices pre-3.0 ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I suggest using http://nineoldandroids.com/ , its from the same maker of the ActionBarSherlock project, it introduces a support ObjectAnimator that works from API 1 onwards.

Comment: but, how to integrate nineoldandroids with support fragment animation?

Comment: This is a useful library and giving backward support @nobre said.

Comment: Sadly this seems to be the case even after appcompat-v7 18.0 :(

Comment: Even for appcompat-v7 20.0. However I would not expect that anymore.

Comment: Welp, not in AppCompat v21, either. Hopefully, we'll get this someday.

Comment: Not in AppCompat v22, either.

Comment: Not in appcompat-v7:23.0.1 as well.

Answer (score 2):

[`Property Animation`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) **Introduced in Android 3.0 (API level 11)**

For support lower android version, (I didn't try it, but you can use)

[Nine Old Androids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/) [Download](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/archive/master.zip)

Android library for using the Honeycomb (Android 3.0) animation API on all versions of the platform back to 1.0!.

Also Look at this blog [Fragment Transactions Reference](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.in/2012_06_01_archive.html)

and this SO question [Android Fragment standard transition not animating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718111/android-fragment-standard-transition-not-animating)

Comment: AFAIK, the support library does not include the property animation classes.

Comment: Call requires API level 12 (current min is 11): 
  android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator#scaleX

Comment: Nine Old Androids is now deprecated.