# Fragments and animations android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a question. This is possible to animate fragment. This is what I mean: I click on the button and from right side showing fragment.Something like you go to next page when you are reading pdf. If yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read these questions:

- [Fragment standard transition not animating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718111/android-fragment-standard-transition-not-animating)
- [Android Fragments and animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817900/android-fragments-and-animation)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty hard to make iOs like page transition, but if you simply need something to swipe from one page to another you can check `ViewPager` view from android support library. I think this is exactly what you are looking for.

EDIT: [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)