# new facebook android application like view

Tags: android, facebook, android-side-navigation

As i want to display number of cities on a left side of a screen just like following-it is a new Facebook android application.

when you click on bar shown as a red square around it,the list view on a left side comes into picture after sliding a right part.

[image: Facebook Front Screen]

so how is it possible to do it to show list view on a right side by sliding it and another activity on a left side

Comment: Hi Hunt,Please share the solution you got for this.I am also looking for the same.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? I started building my own component, but it does not work properly

Comment: Any sucess ? This kind of UI is common now even you can see in the google currents also, I am not in touch with android at Application level from last one year.. If anybody knows plz let it share to others also..

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the new [Fragments API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) and then also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817900/android-fragments-and-animation) which tells you about adding animations to your `Fragment` transactions.

[Fragments For All](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html)

[Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)

[Android Compatibility: Working with Fragments](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/)

Comment: Fragments APIs requires Android 3.X i guess and i am looking for Android 2.X

Comment: If you use the Compatability Package in your project, Fragments are supported down to 1.6. Posted link in my answer.

Comment: I have added the compatible jar file , but can you tell me where can i find the running samples of fragments api ?

Comment: ApiDemos: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html#Fragment

Comment: Well i tried those examples and even the example that you posted i.e. Android Compatibility:Working with fragments but i haven't seen a functionality of dual view in which half screen is covered with list view and another with image view , so how to do that  ?

Comment: i successfully tried working dual view , now the main concern is sliding back n forth with a compatibility and i dont have any idea abt it :(