# swap fragment in an activity via animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to swap two fragment in an activity via animation.Suppose PageA is for fragement A and left side on the screen and PageB is for fragment B i.e. on the right side of the screen. Now i want that when i click a button on pageA then PageA will move to the right side of the screen with some transition animation.

I tried the below code to replace the position

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new FragB());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Looking for some clue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animate the transition between fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments)

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Old questiion and you probably already figured it out, but for future reference:

here's what you use to set a custom animation when you replace a fragment via code:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment, "fragment");
// Start the animated transition.
ft.commit();
```

Here is an example of the slide_in_left animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
  <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fromXDelta="-100%"
   android:toXDelta="0"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
   android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

Note that this is the animation if you are using the compatibility library. Instead if you are using and SDK with native support for the FragmentManager then your animation will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
  <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="x" 
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:valueFrom="-1280"
    android:valueTo="0" 
    android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

This is because the compatibility library does not support the new objectAnimator type and instead only implement the old animation framework.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer. Note that the order matters! You need to have the setCustomAnimations() call before the add/replace calls!

Comment: So which approach should u use if u want best comp?

Comment: These different animations are not exactly equal. You are assuming the width of your fragment is equal to 1280 by using a valueFrom of -1280. If the width was greater it won't start completely off screen.

Comment: U can use the predefined animations from the android namespace instead: transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

Comment: The predefined animations trigger a runtimeexception, FWIW, because they rely on the "translate" tag.

Comment: @egfconnor Have been looking for a solution to this, found a very long answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372436/doing-a-push-fragment-animation

is there any other way?

Comment: @alexsummers I recommend just using the support fragments instead of the actual fragments even on higher APIs.

Comment: @egfconnor But then I seem to get "Type mismatch: cannot convert from FragmentPreferences to Fragment" cuz im extending PreferenceFragment. 

PS: Just made the changes will update it once I have a solution

Comment: Is there an example of a slide_right_out in the objectAnimator framework you can offer?

Comment: why doesn't the "support" library support `objectAnimator` ??