# swapping fragments by hide and show with slide transition causes both to vanish

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, swipe-gesture, android-sliding

I'm trying to animate the transition between a pair of fragments using `transaction.show` and `transaction.hide` to swap fragments. I thought it would be simpler than using `replace` as I understand this instantiates new fragments.

(The fragments would be reused possibly hundred+ of times, leading to high backstack memory usage, and managing the backstack would be a pain when I have a database saving all the fragment info anyway)

When I use

`transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_out_right, R.animator.slide_in_left)`

to animate the transition (or its reverse analog), the animation works but the fragment vanishes after the transition.

My transition animations are defined in XML as below - based in that given in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876126/swap-fragment-in-an-activity-via-animation/9856449#9856449).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set> 
    <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="1280"
    android:duration="500"
    />
</set>
```

- I am not using the support library.
- I am using one framelayout for both fragments, because I thought it would be simpler.
- The problem is similar in nature to that of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876126/swap-fragment-in-an-activity-via-animation/9856449#9856449), but there 2 framelayouts are used for each fragment, and the problem only occurs when 2 transitions occur within the 300ms animation time. The author found a workaround which is to use `AnimatorSet` on each Layout. As an android novice I'm not sure what (s)he means or how I would go about doing this.

Any idea where I'm going wrong? Is there another way to animate such a simple fragment transition as the person above seems to have done? Could it be a bug? Thank you.