# Android. Extending FrameLayout. Couldn't find setter/getter for property xFraction exception

Tags: android, animation, transition, android-framelayout

I have extended FrameLayout class for making slide-in slide-out animation on fragment transition. I want to get xFraction value programmatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@+drawable/logo" />

    <com.example.helpers.CustomFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

CustomFrameLayout looks like

```
public class CustomFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {


    public CustomFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public float getXFraction() {
        return getX() / getWidth();
    }

    public void setXFraction(float xFraction) {
        final int width = getWidth();
        setX((width > 0) ? (xFraction * width) : -9999);
    }
}
```

An exception is thrown when animation is starting after button click:

```
Can't find native method using JNI, use reflectionjava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='setXFraction' signature='(F)V' in class Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout;
02-17 13:57:33.369: E/PropertyValuesHolder(12223): Couldn't find setter/getter for property xFraction with value type float
```

[Animate the transition between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments?answertab=active#tab-top) - i got my idea from there. But it doesn't work. Help me please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372436/doing-a-push-fragment-animation?answertab=active#tab-top - i have found the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to call method: setXFraction() on the parent `RelativeLayout` instead on your `com.example.helpers.CustomFrameLayout`.

You should get reference to your `CustomFrameLayout` like this (assuming you already have reference to your parent layout named `parentRelativeLayout`):

```
CustomFrameLayout customFrameLayout = (CustomFrameLayout) parentRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.fragment);
```

Now you can call `setXFraction()` on the proper reference e.g.:

```
customFrameLayout.setXFraction(25.4);
```

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
      parentAct.setTransaction(getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction());
      parentAct.getTransaction().setCustomAnimations(
        R.anim.slide_from_right_to_screen,
        R.anim.slide_from_screen_to_left);
      parentAct.getTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,
        parentAct.getNativeLoginFr());
      parentAct.getTransaction().commit();
     }      - so i don't call this method, it should work itself

Comment: my slide_from_right_to_screen.xml content is <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:propertyName="xFraction"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />

Answer (score 0):

Whatever view you are trying to animate should have setXFraction method.

If you are inflating this entire xml, it would check for setXFraction in your relative layout.

I guess getNativeLoginFr is give your view and it is inflating the entire xml..

You need to only inflate that FrameLayout for your animation to work.