# Android fragment transition on back navigation to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have 2 fragments the first contains a button which on clicked opens a fragment with a `ListView` in it. I have a shared element transition for the button to transition into the new fragment (root layout) but I would also like to have this transition in reverse (the list fragment contracts into the button again).

However currently I detect the list item click and send an event to the Activity which pops the listview fragment off the backstack (`popBackStackImmediate()`) hence does not show the transition.

Is there a good way to allow back navigation while preserving reverse transition to work as well?

Comment: I have used the `FractionTranslateLinearLayout` class from the answer here, it works well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372436/doing-a-push-fragment-animation

Answer (score 0):

did you try this:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.popBackStack();
fm.executePendingTransactions();
```

PS: use `getSupportFragmentManager()` if you're using the support library else use `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: doesn't make a difference :(

Comment: could you add some code? how are you adding the first fragment ? how are you adding the list fragment ? how are you going back to the first one?