# Android fragment animation layer

Tags: android, animation, fragment, translate

How to change fragment animation layer. I mean if first *old* fragment is desapearing then *new* fragment is comming over them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doing a push fragment animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372436/doing-a-push-fragment-animation)

Answer (score 1):

Use **Shared elements between fragments**

### a) Enable Window Content Transition

**values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="MaterialAnimations" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    ...
</style>
```

### b) Define a common transition name

**layout/fragment_a.xml**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/small_blue_icon"
        style="@style/MaterialAnimations.Icon.Small"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        android:transitionName="@string/blue_name" />
```

**layout/fragment_b.xml**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/big_blue_icon"
        style="@style/MaterialAnimations.Icon.Big"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        android:transitionName="@string/blue_name" />
```

### c) Start a fragment with a shared element

To do this you need to include shared element transition information as part of the `FragmentTransaction` process.

```
FragmentB fragmentB = FragmentB.newInstance(sample);

// Defines enter transition for all fragment views
Slide slideTransition = new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT);
slideTransition.setDuration(1000);
sharedElementFragment2.setEnterTransition(slideTransition);

// Defines enter transition only for shared element
ChangeBounds changeBoundsTransition = TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_bounds);
fragmentB.setSharedElementEnterTransition(changeBoundsTransition);

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content, fragmentB)
        .addSharedElement(blueView, getString(R.string.blue_name))
        .commit();
```

Output :

[image]

for more detail visit this : https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations