# How to make cardView slide up and down animation in android?

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager, android-cardview, slideup

I am building an android application similar to inshorts. I wanna to slide my cardView up and down. What I am doing yet - I am parsing the data from server using webAPI then using BaseAdapter displaying in cardView. But now I need on swipe up it should move up and next position card should be displayed  .

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with **ViewPager** and **Fragments** then you need to put slide animation with view pager. For horizontal slide you can see developers reference http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html.

After that you need to modify view pager slightly so that it behave like vertical instead of horizontal and you can achieve this with below code:

```
public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {

public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    // The majority of the magic happens here
    setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
    // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
    setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}

private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
 private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;
    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0);

        }  else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
            // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
            view.setAlpha(1);
            // Counteract the default slide transition
            view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

            //set Y position to swipe in from top
            float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
            view.setTranslationY(yPosition);
            view.setScaleX(1);
            view.setScaleY(1);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // [0,1]
            view.setAlpha(1);

            // Counteract the default slide transition
            view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);


            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                    + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }

    }

}

/**
 * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
 */
private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
    float width = getWidth();
    float height = getHeight();

    float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
    float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

    ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

    return ev;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
    return intercepted;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by using `fragments` and `ViewPager` to load the pages, and you can specify **Property Animation** to animate the fragments.

If you are new to fragments, try beginning from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

And then you need `ViewPager` to swipe between pages. [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Property Animation is often used to animate native fragments(Android.App.Fragment) . [see this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html)
and see this to [swap fragments using Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876126/swap-fragment-in-an-activity-via-animation)