# Hide previous Fragment when adding new one

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 `Fragment`'s - A and B.
In order to switch from `Fragment` A to `Fragment` B I'm using this function:

```
public static void swapFragments(FragmentManager fragmentManager, int containerViewId, Fragment newFragment)    {

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(containerViewId, newFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Let's say `Fragment` A takes the entire screen's area and `Fragment` B takes only the upper half of the screen.

**The problem:** When switching to `Fragment` B, the user is still able to see `Fragment` A at the lower half of the screen...

How can I hide `Fragment` A when switching to `Fragment` B ?

p.s: I don't want to use `replace` instead of `add` in the `swap` function above - I don't want `Fragment` A's `onCreate()` to be called each time the user navigate back from `Fragment` B to `Fragment` A...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, without any other option, I've just took care that `Fragment` B will occupy the entire screen so that `Fragment` A can't be seen.

More adjustments should have n=been done due to Android's bugs, such as: [Google's stupid bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15537)

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe move Fragment A? E.g. slide it down when Fragment B appears? Simply move it outside the screen. Something like what's discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817900/android-fragments-and-animation)