# Change multiple fragments from ONE ActionTab

Tags: android

i have tried multiple times to add **two fragments into One Action Tab**.when i press the action tab "Search" i want to load one fragment when i **swipe it will go to 2nd fragment** under the Action tab.please find below the code i Used.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.swipetabs;
import com.tabs.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.comparenow.*;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {

    ActionBar action_bar;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ImageView creditCards;
    Fragment fragement;
    Fragment fragement1;
    Fragment fragement2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);


        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdoptor(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                action_bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        action_bar=getActionBar();
        //action_bar.setBackgroundDrawable(d)
        action_bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab tab1=action_bar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Login");

        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab2=action_bar.newTab();
        tab2.setText("Compare Now");
        tab2.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab3=action_bar.newTab();
        tab3.setText("Search");
        tab3.setTabListener(this);

        action_bar.addTab(tab1);
        action_bar.addTab(tab2);
        action_bar.addTab(tab3);

    }

    public void switchToFragmentB(){
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
     }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //this is the code
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        String name=(String)tab.getText().toString();

         // compare it to the tab you  would like to do something with        
        if (name == "Search") {
            //load the 1st fragment
            fragement1= new CreditCards();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                            android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.store_fragment_container, fragment).commit();

            //load the 2nd fragment
            fragement2 = new Loginfrag();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                            android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.imageView1,fragement2).commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}


class MyAdoptor extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{

    public MyAdoptor(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Fragment fragement=null;
        if(arg0==0)
        {
            fragement=new Loginfrag();
        }
        if(arg0==1)
        {
            fragement=new Comparefrag();
        }
        if(arg0==2)
        {
            fragement=new Searchfrag();
        }



        System.out.print("<><><><>");
        return fragement;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }

}
```

**CreditCards.java (Fragment) /Loginfrag .java (Fragement ) both are same its's got corresponsing xml files as well.**

```
package com.comparenow;

import com.example.swipetabs.R;
import com.example.swipetabs.R.layout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class CreditCards extends Fragment {

    public CreditCards() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.creditcards_c, container, false);
    }
```

**i have problem with below code segment,im not sure Its parameters.**

```
fragement1= new CreditCards();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                            android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.store_fragment_container, fragment).commit();

            //load the 2nd fragment
            fragement2 = new Loginfrag();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                            android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.imageView1,fragement2).commit();

    }
```

Comment: I think u need to call next fragment after first 1st finish animation so need to add animation listener - see this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120372/performing-action-after-fragment-transaction-animation-is-finished

Comment: @Neha im only concern about changing fragements under one action Tab

Comment: And if you do change multiple fragments under one action tab what issue u facing ?

Comment: @Neha i have posted the code segment which i'm getting Errors.thanks for let me know.

Comment: where u initializing fragment .. in code i can see fragement1 and fragement2 ..where is fragment ?

Comment: @Neha i have initialized those in my MainActivity.java please find below the code o used

Comment: Are you getting this error - "The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, Fragment)"

Answer (score 1):

In general, I believe what you're looking for is to create a `ViewPager` within a `Fragment` within a `ViewPager`.

Your `MainActivity` is more or less right, but you should forget everything below `viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition())` in `onTabSelected()`. Instead of using `Searchfrag` in your pager adapter's `getItem()` method, you're going to need to create and use a parent `Fragment` for both `Searchfrag` and whatever other `Fragment` you want to scroll to in the Search tab. This `Fragment` can be really simple and contain only a `ViewPager` and pager adapter. In this parent `Fragment's` pager adapter, you'll write the `getItem()` method to return `Searchfrag` for item 0 and whatever other fragment you want to scroll to for item 1. Both of these `Fragment's` will look like they are under your Search tab.

For example, the `FragmentPagerAdapter` that will hold `Searchfrag` and the other `Fragment` should have a `getItem()` method like the following:

```
public static class SampleFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SampleFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        if(arg0 == 0){
            return new Searchfrag();
        } else {
            return new OtherFragmentUnderSearchTab();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

}
```

This parent `Fragment` (let's call it `ParentFragment`) should replace `Searchfrag` in the `getItem()` method of `MyAdoptor` like so:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Fragment fragement=null;
    if(arg0==0)
    {
        fragement=new Loginfrag();
    }
    if(arg0==1)
    {
        fragement=new Comparefrag();
    }
    if(arg0==2)
    {
        fragement=new ParentFragment();
    }



    System.out.print("<><><><>");
    return fragement;

}
```