# How to check finish setCustomAnimations when replace fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my activity or fragment I used method:

```js
 public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, 0);
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.replace(R.id.mFrameContainer, fragment);
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

when replace fragment. I run but in some screen have load data from sever, it's lag when show fragment so I want when animation finish I will call method load data. So how I can check finish animation replace fragment. I search and see in stack over but I still can't do it.
If you have answer for my question, please share to me!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Give [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120372/performing-action-after-fragment-transaction-animation-is-finished) a shot. You'll have to change it to an `Animation`, but it allows you to use an `AnimationListener`.

Comment: @DillonBurton How I can call onCreateAnimation instaed of setCustomAnimations

Comment: You will still call everything like you have it, except you will override `onCreateAnimation` inside of your fragment, and run your code inside of `onAnimationEnd`.

Comment: @DillonBurton it mean I must remove  transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, 0); and add R.anim.slide_in_right in onCreateAnimation ?

Comment: I'll add an answer to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of importing `import android.app.Fragment;`, use `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`. Change `getFragmentManager` in your `replaceFragment` method with `getSupportFragmentManager`. Then, in your fragment class, add the following:

```
@Override
public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {

    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), nextAnim);

    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO: This is where you will put your code for when the animation is finished
        }
    });

    return anim;
}
```

Put the code you want to execute after in `onAnimationEnd`.