# How to Listen to Transition Completed on Android Fragment Transition with Navigation Component?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-transitions

I have this one fragment that loads tons of data and display it into recyclerView. If I open this fragment directly without waiting for transition completed the transition will become choppy because the thread is throttled by recyclerView update data

So I want to delay this update data until fragment transition completed.

But sadly I have yet to find any way to listen to fragment transition completed so my current approach is to delay the data update for several miliseconds until using Handler() , but I believe this is very hacky and not elegant solution

```
Handler().postDelayed({
//do something
}, 500)
```

I need help to know what method should I call to listen to the fragment transition completed . Thank youuu

Answer (score 3):

hmm I somehow did it with onCreateAnimation following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15399035/616280)

```
override fun onCreateAnimation(transit: Int, enter: Boolean, nextAnim: Int): Animation? {
    val anim: Animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, nextAnim)
    anim.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {}
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {}
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
            if (enter) {
                //load and update recyclerView here
            }
        }
    })
    return anim
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question, but could we use a timer instead of a delay?

Comment: @Furkan the problem with timer/delay etc is when I change the transition duration it would break and the screen become laggy again. I need to make sure that the transition keeps smooth however I tweak the values

Answer (score 2):

Fragments offer two ways of avoiding this problem:

1. You can avoid *starting* your transition until your data is loaded by [postponing your transition](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/animate#postpone). This ensures that your RecyclerView is already populated with data that can be used for shared element transitions, etc. This is the general recommendation and ensures a smooth transition on all versions of Fragments.
2. When using [Fragment 1.3.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0) or higher, your fragment will not reach the resumed state until any transitions or Animators (specifically not Animations) are complete. This allows you to use `onResume()` as a signal that your transitions are complete.

Comment: Hi, Ian! I'm using Fragment `1.3.1` and `onResume()` seems to be called right after `navigate()` is. I also tried using version `1.3.0`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: So are you using Animators? Animations? Framework Transitions? AndroidX Transitions? If the very last, what version of AndroidX Transitions? Make sure you are using the latest ([Transition 1.4.1](http://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/transition#1.4.1)).

Comment: I'm using custom-defined sliding Animations with the Android Navigation Component.

Comment: As mentioned very specifically in my answer, Animations are the one exception to the timing of `onResume()` (have you considered using a [Slide Transition](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/transition/Slide)?). Postponing works with any time of effect, including Animations, and allows you to fully load your data before starting the Animation. That's why mentioned that approach first :-)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that :-)

Comment: What if some actions required to perform right after transitions end? Specifically, I do not need to load data, but need to change visibility of GLSurfaceView? If GL View  is visible while transitions still performs - it appears on-top of all view hierarchy and also over the fragment from which exit was performed

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use animations, rather than Transitions or Animators, you can extract the animation duration into an integer resource and set the animation duration to it:

```xml
<!-- values/durations.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="animation_duration">220</integer>
</resources>
```

```xml
<!-- anim/transition.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <alpha android:duration="@integer/animation_duration" android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

And then retrieve it in your fragment:

```
val animationDuration = requireContext().resources.getInteger(R.integer.animation_duration)
Handler().postDelayed({
//do something
}, animationDuration)
```