# How to add animation for fragment on android 2.1?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-fragmentactivity

From this topic.
[Android Fragments and animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817900/android-fragments-and-animation)

I try to use [nineoldandroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library but i can't use objectAnimator in xml file like below example.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
  <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="x" 
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:valueFrom="-1280"
    android:valueTo="0" 
    android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

how to add animation for fragment on android 2.1 ? (i use Compatibility Package.)

Comment: On NineOldAndroids: it can't be done as per told by NineOldAndroids creator himself.

See:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/issues/43