# Android: Customize slide layouts

Tags: android, layout, slide

I'm making a new app that has a layout as follows:

**LinearLayout1 LinearLayout2**

**Breadcrumb**

**Main Content**

When user clicks "linear layout2", the screen will slide left until "linear layout1" is hidden. Then a new activity with title is "linear layout2" will be shown.

When user clicks "linear layout1", the screen will slide right until "linear layout2" is hidden. Then a new activity with title is "linear layout2" will be shown.

I do some researches but cannot find a solution. Could you please give me some tips and examples so that I can go ahead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is slightly confusing so I'm going to make an assumption.

Is [LinearLayout1 LinearLayout2 Breadcrumb] suppose to be navigation or tabs that when selected insert their corresponding content into the Main Content?

If so I would suggest using fragments for each piece of content. Then when you click the navigation/tab, perform an animation of the fragment which slides the content in and out.

See the google docs for how to use fragments:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

See another stackoverflow answer for how to do the slide animation:
[Android Fragments and animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817900/android-fragments-and-animation)