# Translate a fragment away from the screen

Tags: android, animation, fragment

I want to translate my fragment away from the screen i.e. from middle to left and then hide in the left. Isn't this the right code? This wouldn't work. Please tell where i am going wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
     <translate
           android:fromXDelta="0%p"
           android:toXDelta="-100%p"
           android:duration="500">
     </translate>
</set>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "This wouldn't work" how do you include this animation resource to your code?

Comment: This didn't work. Used Animations in the `onCreateView()` method of fragments.

Comment: look the link that Anis sent you.you don't set animation in the onCreateView() method

Answer (score 0):

It Depend on you current position of your Frament, to animate fragment show hide, see this post: [Android Fragments and animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817900/android-fragments-and-animation)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an `objectAnimator` Animation