# Slide between views in Android

Tags: android, view, sliding

In an Android activity, I am showing a View

On click of a button, I want to replace the current View with a slide, meaning the current view slides from right to left and the new views shows. Similarly, when the user now presses the back button, the previous views slides back from left to right

Please help with a suitable example

Comment: It's now deprecated, but Android has a built in SlidingDrawer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Here is a tutorial coving how to do basically exactly [what you are asking about](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/)

Answer (score 1):

Use two Fragments, one for each view, than you can create two slide animations(in and out animation), via an XML file (or programmatically), which are used to slide the new fragment in and the old out.

Read the [Fragment guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for detailed information, an example, how to use transaction animation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817900/android-fragments-and-animation).