# Fragment slide animation is replacing first fragment before animating

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've followed instructions from dmanargias answer here: [Android Fragments and animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817900/android-fragments-and-animation)

The animations themselves work, however the initial animation when adding a fragment is doing something strange.  The initial fragment appears to be replaced with the new fragment before the animation is started.

e.g.  One would expect an animation of 
A <- B (B sliding from right to cover A)

However as soon as the action starts A instantly becomes B and you get an animation of 
B <- B.

When popping the stack you get a correct animation of A -> B (B sliding away revealing A)

This is the code that adds a fragment:

```
CategoryFragment newFragment = CategoryFragment.newInstance();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit);

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, newFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Any ideas why this would happen and if there's a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    final CategoryFragment newFragment = CategoryFragment.newInstance();
    final View container = findViewById(R.id.fragment);
    container.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit);
            transaction.replace(container.getId(), newFragment).commit();
            currentFragment = cardFragment;
        }
    }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same problem, but with different animations. 
Check that `android:shareInterpolator` is not set to true in your xml animations.