# fragment transition does not work?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I need to create effect when fragment replace like side_in_left OR slide_out_right.

I used:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

`OR`

Try this solution **[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817900/android-fragments-and-animation)**

**but both are not working**

---

This is code what I am using for replace fragment:

```
FragmentFirst dragabbleFragment = new FragmentFirst();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, dragabbleFragment).commit();
```

Comment: Have you placed the animation XML in anim folder? If so, you need to use `R.anim not android.R.anim`

Comment: I am using predefined value so, I used android.R.anim.*** and I also tried other but it also not working. As I mention Solution LINK ... @Nun'eChai

Comment: For the other to work you need to put the relevant xml files in the Anim folder, I have used the same and it works fine.

Comment: Could you please update that xml file and the code snippet. Beacuse I tried many solution from SO ... not working still  @Nun'eChai

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, dragabbleFragment).commit();
```

I may be wrong but it could be because you're calling `beginTransaction()` twice and you're applying the animation to the first `FragmentTransaction` but calling `replace(...)` on the second.

Try...

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
ft.replace(R.id.container, dragabbleFragment).commit();
```

EDIT: Try...

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(...).replace(...).commit();
```

Obviously replace the `...` parts with the bits you need - I left them out to keep the example short.

Comment: replace give me error :  The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, FragmentFirst) ..

Comment: Does `FragmentFirst` extend `Fragment`?

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, dragabbleFragment).commit();  this is working fine

Comment: i used this FragmentFirst dragabbleFragment = new FragmentFirst(); but i found this also from SO solution : CustomFragment newCustomFragment = CustomFragment.newInstance();  when I applied this newInstance() does not exist for me.

Comment: You have to create your own `getInstance()` method in your `FragmentFirst` class if you want to use that way of doing things. As for the other issue, I don't understand why `getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(...).commit()` would work but not the way I suggested. Try chaining it all - see my edit above.

Comment: I tried but not working .. May be I did something wrong .. I start with new demo and try to resolve this .. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @AM : OK, good luck. One other thing - as you are using the support libraries make sure all classes are from the android.support.v4 library. The standard `Fragment` and `FragmentTransaction` (for instance) aren't compatible with the support library classes.