# Add Animations to Fragment When replacing

Tags: android

I am trying out a simple fragment code demo ,where i replacing the fragment on orientation change

**CODE:**

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();

        /**
         * Check the device orientation and act accordingly
         */
        if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            /**
             * Landscape mode of the device
             */             

            LS_Fragment ls_fragment = new LS_Fragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, ls_fragment);
        } else {
            /**
             * Portrait mode of the device
             */
                PM_Fragment pm_fragment = new PM_Fragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, pm_fragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Now after searching the net i found that i have to use

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations()
```

but i am not able to understand how to write the animations xml and give it to the .setCustomAnimations() function

Comment: @Ando Masahashi why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just passed your `In and Out Animation` as arguments to `.setCustomAnimations(in,out)`

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left2, R.anim.slide_out_right2);
```

Go to this [fragments-translate-animation](http://trickyandroid.com/fragments-translate-animation/) for demo or

Go to this [android-switch-fragment-with-animation.html](http://fancifulandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-switch-fragment-with-animation.html) for demo

and also take a look at this [Android Fragment Animation SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817900/android-fragments-and-animation)

Comment: i wanted to know what to write in the contents of R.anim.slide_in_left2 and R.anim.slide_out_right2

given my fragment transition is based on orientation change

Comment: @M D

I tried the following but the animations arnt working

http://pastebin.com/0yHvqeT8

Answer (score 0):

To animate the transition between fragments you use the Fragment Manager to create a Fragment Transaction.

Within each Fragment Transaction you can specify in and out animations that will be used for show and hide respectively (or both when replace is used).

The following code shows how you would replace a fragment by sliding out one fragment and sliding the other one in it's place.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// here you have to set your animation xml for in and out transition 
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);

DetailsFragment newFragment = new DetailsFragment();

ft.replace(R.id.details_fragment_container, newFragment, "detailFragment");

// Start the animated transition.
ft.commit();
```

For reference, the XML animation definitions would use the objectAnimator tag. An example of slide_in_left might look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

slide_out_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate
       android:duration="700"
       android:fromXDelta="0%"
       android:toXDelta="100%" >
   </translate>
</set>
```