# Animation between fragment transactions

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I am try to do two animation while navigation from one fragment to other fragment.
When I am in onefragment,On the tab click of activity,current fragment should slide left and on the launch of new fragment it should be sliding from right.

I tried intially using FragmentTransaction's setCustomAnimations(),but it was not successful.

So I am doing animations on status of fragment.So the SlideLeft transititionm,I am doing in Stop() of the fragment,While SlideIn transistion has been done on OnAcitvityCreated() of the fragment.

Please let me know Is this correct way or any other appropriate way to handle this

Comment: Refer this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817900/android-fragments-and-animation

Comment: You should look up how to make that work with support fragments,  it is different than in the 3.0 version. And you cannot use nine old androids for it...

Comment: Use fragment manager to apply any transitions.