# New fragment transitioning over white background instead of old fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-transitions

I am trying to transition between two fragments using this animation.

Problem I have is when I transition using the following code. The animation slides in the new fragment over a white background instead of the old fragment.

I want to either use .replace or create the exact same functionality as replace.
I also want the animation to slide the new fragment over the old fragment.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = MainActivity.instance.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);


    transaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_content, fragment);
    transaction.commit();

    try {
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Animations:

Slide in right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

slide out right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

Comment: Still looking for an answer, any help will be appreciated

Comment: same problem. @Darren if you solved this problem, please, share your implementation)

Comment: Something similar and potentially applicable:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561523/remove-the-white-screen-a-slide-window-transition-creates-when-it-starts

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part is you have to define all the **Anim** field in the action.
something like bellow:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
    android:name="sample.presentation.view.fragments.profile.ProfileFragment"
    android:label="fragment_profile"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" >
   
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_profileFragment_to_personalInfoFragment"
        app:destination="@id/personalInfoFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
        app:exitAnim="@android:anim/slide_out_right"
        app:popEnterAnim="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@android:anim/slide_out_right"/>
</fragment>
```