# How to programmatically animate shifting fragments?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-animation

I want to click a button and have certain View containers change size smoothly/transitionally. Can this be done in Android?

Comment: you should google it mate!

Comment: I did! I couldn't find what I was looking for, so I asked here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Fragments and animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817900/android-fragments-and-animation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by view container you mean ViewGroup you can use a ValueAnimator. It's a simple timing engine that you can use to do animation.

For example if you want to animate a change of height for a RelativeLayout rl to finalHeight from startHeight in 400ms you can do :

```
ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
va.setDuration(400);
va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                Float value = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                rl.height = (int) (startHeight + (finalHeight - startHeight) * value);
                rl.requestLayout();
            }
        });
```

You can use different interpolator and customize the ValueAnimator to do some really nice effect.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html