# Fragment Transition skipped the first time because of RecylerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-transitions

I have a recylerview with some items the last item is add item. If you press on it, it opens a new fragment from bottom up to let you choose some categories( something like airbnb filters) in this fragment I have 3 recyclerviews and some other items, and if I delete the recyclerviews the fragment shows smoothly with transition, but with them the fragment gets delayed.

Example:
So you press on the Add Item, you wait 1 second then the fragment just pops up. After you press back it animates like it should and if you press again on add item it smoothly animates like it should in the first place, maybe because it is cached?

Any ideas how to approach this issue?

Comment: I think this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817900/android-fragments-and-animation

Comment: Thank you and I looked it but it just shows how to do transitions :) and doesn't solve the problem that I'm having.