# Add book page flip animation with fragment

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app which will mostly look like a book
I'm using fragments in the app
So I need to animate the transition between fragments to look like flipping a book page
So how can I achieve that.

Comment: What have you already tried, what are you stuck on? Stack Overflow is used to help debug problems in ones code. Please also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: as i mentioned above i don't know how to add the animation i have the fragment and a viewpager2 but can't add the animation so iam asking here so that someone may mention a library or a way to do so

Comment: I don't have any experience with Android development but after a quick Google search I get things like this: https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-add-flip-animations-to-your-android-app-814902/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817900/android-fragments-and-animation other than that I am afraid I cannot help any further.